# dbcontext throwAmbiguousMatchException

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, serialization, dbcontext

i try to serialize a class into xml.
after the serialization , i would like to update the statusid.
I'm able to find the first order and alter the statusId , when goes to the 2nd orderid,here is where i encountered the  ambiguous match found error.

here is the main method:

```
 using (var Context = new Context())
            {


                var orderRepo = new OrderRepository(Context);

                foreach (var orderId in orderIds)
                {
                    var order = orderRepo.Find(orderId);
                    order.orderStatusID = 5;

                }
                orderRepo.Save();
            }
```

in the OrderRepository.cs

```
     public Order Find(int id)
            {
                return _context.Orders.Find(id);
            }

   public void Save()
        {

            try
            {
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

               _logger.Error(ex);
            }

        }
```

order.cs:

```
  [XmlRoot("Orders")]
    [NotMapped]
    public class OrderCollection
    {

        public OrderCollection() { Orders = new List<Order>(); }

        [XmlElement("Order")]
        [NotMapped]
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class Order
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("date")]
        public DateTime createdDate
        {
            get
            {
                return (_createdDate == default(DateTime))
                   ? DateTime.Now
                   : _createdDate;
            }

            set { _createdDate = value; }
        }
        private DateTime _createdDate = default(DateTime);

        public string firstName { get; set; }

        public string lastName { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public int orderStatusID { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Looks like your code is finding multiple matches for a given order id.  What is your underlying data store?

Comment: i have double checked the data, all single entry. it's completely fine when i only look up the 2nd one

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a null in your orderIds list?

Answer (score 0):

turn out to be an entity had two members with the same name and different casing. One was a field from the database, and one was a navigation property. Just renaming one of the two solved the problem.